# Preserve ViewModel values when @EnvironmentObject value changes - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, mvvm, viewmodel, observedobject, environmentobject

I am looking to preserve the `viewModel.counter` value even when `valueComingFromParent` value changes.

Right now, when `Incrementer` button is clicked it increments `viewModel.counter` value. But when `Toast` button is clicked, it changes value of a property in `valueComingFromParent`. and at the same time `viewModel.counter` value resets to `0`

```
struct ChildView: View {

@ObservedObject var viewModel = ChildViewModel()
@EnvironmentObject var valueComingFromParent: SomeOtherViewModel

var body: some View {
        VStack {
                    Button("Toast", action: {
                        
                        valueComingFromParent.toast.toggle()
                    })
                    
                    Button("Incrementer \(viewModel.counter)", action: {
                        viewModel.counter += 1
                    })
                }
        }
}
```

Can anybody tell me how can I preserve the value of `viewModel.counter` even if `valueComingFromParent` value changes.

Thanks

Comment: Use StateObject instead of ObservedObject

Comment: these consistency problems are why we don't use view model objects in SwiftUI

Comment: what do you suggest as an alternative to view model approach? @malhal

Comment: The solution given by @jnpdx worked for above issue but I am still facing some other issues. For some reason the child view navigates back to parent view when Toast button is clicked. and Navigation height gets increased as well. strange issues.